# How to Filter only Character on PHP String?

Tags: php, regex, string, filter

I have String Like This

```
<?php

$str = "3451231 3123 Rotary-moulder";

?>
```

and I need a Function that Only filter the Character(Alphabet)

and the result is "Rotary-moulder"

I have been googling ang Find this Script

```
<?php

$str = '06516161 065165161 ini adalah percobaan';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);


$var = implode(' ', $matches[0]);

echo $var;

?>
```

Thats Work Fine and the Result is only Number. How can I get Only Alphabet Character?

I'm Still Not Understand how to reverse that function.

Any one can help me?

Im very appreciated Your Answer.

Comment: The "opposite" would be `'![a-z-]+!'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $string);
```

**edit**

If you want to keep the `-` try  this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z-]/i', '', $string);
```

Comment: I may have taken them too literally, I'll update it to include dashes as well.

Comment: @JohnConde HI It Work Well, but no spacing. Can it include with space or no character?

Comment: @JohnConde I have find it $string = preg_replace('/[^a-z- ]/i', '', $str); thanks So Much

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $str = '06516161 065165161 ini adalah percobaan';
    preg_match_all('!\D+!', $str, $matches);


    $var = implode(' ', $matches[0]);

    echo $var;
?>
```

You have to replace small letter 'd' with 'D' in preg_match_all. 'D' uses for Any non-digit match.